# Jmeter fails to insert document to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, groovy, jmeter

I could connect Jmeter to MongoDB successfully but inserting document to Mongo DB fails. Note that I Am able to insert the document directly to Mongo using same credentials.

- Successfully Connected to Mongo by following code:

  ```
  import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
  import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
  import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
  import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;
  import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
  import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
  import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
  import org.bson.Document;
  import java.util.Arrays;


  try {

  String mongoUser = vars.get("mongouser");
  String userDB = vars.get("userdb");
  char[] password = vars.get("password").toCharArray();
  MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(mongoUser, 
  userDB, password);
  MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
  .applyToClusterSettings {builder -> 
  builder.hosts(Arrays.asList(new 
  ServerAddress(InetAddress.getByName(vars.get("mongoHost")),
  vars.get("mongoPort").toInteger())))}
  .build();
  MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);

  MongoDatabase database = 
  mongoClient.getDatabase(vars.get("databaseName"));
  MongoCollection<Document> collection = 
  database.getCollection(vars.get("collectionName"));
  vars.putObject("collection", collection);
  return "Connected to " + vars.get("collectionName");
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
  SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
  SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
  SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e);
  }
  ```

In another sampler as follow I Am trying to Add a document to MongoDB:

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import org.bson.Document;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import java.util.Arrays;

try {


    MongoCollection<Document> collection = vars.getObject("collection");

    Document document = new Document("EmployeeOID",1111111)
        .append("EmployeeName", "Test Automation through Jmeter")
        .append("Employee_Type_OID",4)
        .append("Rank",0)
        .append("Rating",0)
        .append("Score",0)
        .append("Supervisor_OID",56789)
        .append("EmpID","222222T");

    collection.insertOne(document);


Document result = collection.find(eq("EmployeeOID",1111111)).first();
if(result !=null){
String ID =result.get("_id");  
log.info(ID)
ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId(ID);
vars.put('myID', objectId as String);
log.info (vars.get('myID'))
return ;
}
return "Employee not found";
    }
catch (Exception e) {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
    SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e);
}
```

which fails with Error:

Response code: 500
Response message: Exception: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]

Answer (score 1):

`Successfully Connected to Mongo by following code`  that's not true, if you take a closer look into the error details:

> Response code: 500 Response message: Exception: **com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect.** Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=**localhost:27017**, type=UNKNOWN, state=**CONNECTING**, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: **Connection refused: connect**}}]

It appears that you're trying to connect to your local machine at port 27017 and the connection gets refused.

If you really want to work with the MongoDB instance on your local machine - double check that:

- MongoDB server is up and running
- It is listening on port `27017`
- `localhost` may stand for different IP addresses: [loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback), [private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network), IPv4, IPv6, external IP address, etc. and your MongoDB server might be listening on one IP address and JMeter tries to connect to another. Check out [IP Binding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-mongodb-configuration/#ip-binding) chapter of MongoDB documentation to learn more about enabling remote MongoDB access

If your MongoDB instance lives on another machine it means that `mongoHost` JMeter Variable has wrong value, you can double check it using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) combination.